# Gain sole control of Audio Output, DirectSound

Tags: c++, windows, directsound

I am creating a basic signal generator and decided to use my audio card as the analogue output. I chose to use DirectSound because... it seemed like a good option.

I have it up and running quite nicely, but I now realize that my code using secondary buffers and as such any other sounds on the computer get mixed in with my generated signal. This is something of an issue, as when I'm running a motor I don't want it to get sent an MSN poke noise as a command.

In order to gain total control I've attempted to take over the system by setting my cooperative level to DSSCL_WRITEPRIMARY. All in all this strategy is really giving me a headache as I am running into error after error trying to get this set up. The documentation on using the primary buffer isn't great and I can't find any really good examples.

So my question is:

1. Does anyone have a good, working example of taking over and writing to the primarybuffer.
2. Is there a simpler way of outputing a waveform to the audio card, and ensuring that my application has full and sole control?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

only thing I've seen related is:

[Sample - WASAPI exclusive-mode event-driven playback app, including the HD Audio alignment dance](https://matthewvaneerde.wordpress.com/2009/04/03/sample-wasapi-exclusive-mode-event-driven-playback-app-including-the-hd-audio-alignment-dance/)

> Sample WASAPI exclusive-mode event-driven playback app, including amd64 and x86 binaries, source, and a modification of the ac3.wav Dolby Digital test tone to include a “fact” chunk.

A couple of WASAPI exclusive mode sample applications are also here: [Windows Classic Samples, Multimedia, Audio](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/audio)